# Librería en PHP para extraer texto de un PDF

Tags: php, pdf

necesito una libreria que pueda extraer un pdf y acomodarlo en partes entonces mi duda es:

¿existe actualmente alguna librería que saque el texto de un pdf y se pueda acomodar como tu quieras?

ya que he estado buscando y no he tenido mucha suerte al encontrar lo que necesito

agradecería mucho su ayuda, ya que para mi es importante encontrar esa funcionalidad, esta es para php o javascript

saludos

Comment: no crees que para acotar mas aún tu pregunta sería ideal indiques en que lenguaje trabajas, ya que librerías existen de muchos tipos y para muchos lenguajes

Comment: justo ya lo puse

Comment: Si estás usando php5 entonces lo que te puede servir es la librería pdfparser, la cual puedes obtener desde [aquí](https://www.pdfparser.org/):

Comment: lo voy a probar gracias

Comment: hola, has usado esta libreria antes?

Comment: Así es, la utilicé hace tiempo para un proyecto escolar y me facilitó el trabajo en ese momento.

Comment: Rodrigo, te sugiero realices tus preguntas en base a lo definido en [ask], tu pregunta en realidad busca una opinión,saludos.

Comment: Puedes usar también https://pdfparser.org/ revisa : http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/zend-lucene-and-pdf-documents-part-2-pdf-data-extraction